# beforeExit hook not present in ep-mobx-router

Tags: router, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I am using ep-mobx-router v0.2.3 in a react typescript project, which is very similar to [mobx-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-router). The [documentation page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep-mobx-router) shows that beforeExit is a hook present in the package, but when I am trying to use it, it gives error that its not present in ep-mobx-router. I checked in my route.ts file in node modules of ep-mobx-router, only onEnter is present there. What am I doing wrong? How can I use beforeExit with minimal changes to project? I have tried moving to mobx-router, but facing so many dependencies issues.

Comment: Hm, this package is quite weird, it uses mobx-router docs and has mobx-router page as homepage. It also has only 9 downloads this week. Are you sure it is valid package at all? I mean, it might have anything inside, it might be malware or whatever, last time it was published was 3 years ago. No one could be sure because there is no link for the source.

Comment: Not sure about its validity. Got a project where it was configured from the beginning, and now changing that is breaking the code a lot. If we make the change in index.d.ts in node modules, and add beforeExit hook's entry there, it works perfect fine, Not sure how to do this without making change in node modules.